# How to assemble Intel-syntax assembly on Windows using gcc?

Tags: assembly, mingw, x86-64

I've been using Ubuntu up until a few weeks ago and now I'm back on Windows.
I have a test coming up in basic assembly programming. I remember that while I was on Linux I could compile .s assembly files through terminal using gcc file.s, and it all worked fine.

But now that I'm on Windows, it doesn't work so great. Here's the code that I copied from my faculty's website (I didn't write it):

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.data
    fmt_string: .asciz "Hello, world!\n"

.text
.global main

main:
    enter 0,0
    mov rax, 0
    lea rdi, fmt_string
    call printf
    mov rax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

I'm using MinGW in ordere to compile .c and .s files, and here's what I get after tried to compile this code:

[image]

Now, keep in mind that I'm only starting (trying to start) learning assembly so if you go all theoretical on me I'll probably have no idea what you're talking about.

All I want to know is whether I can compile this assembly code on Windows or if I should think about just going back to Linux.

Comment: [use `xor eax, eax` instead of `mov rax, 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617/995714), it's 5/8 bytes shorter and has more advantages. And you don't need to use `lea` to load a constant to a register. Use mov instead

Comment: Short: You cannot. You tried to compile a 64-bit source using Linux calling convention with a 32-bit compiler using Windows calling convention.

Comment: Of course it is possible to use the 64-bit MingW variant to compile 64-bit code... However compiling 64-bit code using the 32-bit variant will get you nowhere.

Comment: The Windows x64 calling convention is different from Linux's x86-64 System V calling convention.  I think x86-64 MinGW would use the Windows calling convention, so you'd need to pass the first arg to printf in RCX, and reserve 32 bytes of shadow space before the `call`.  If you don't want to port code to a different calling convention, you should stick with Linux (or the Linux subsystem for Windows).